# Regex for extracting part of a file path

Tags: regex, impala

I am using regex function in Impala to find the folder name in file path but it doesn't seem to give me correct result

I want to parse out "one" from this file path:

```
/this/one/path/to/hdfs
```

This is the regex which I used:

```
regexp_extract(filepath,'[/]+',0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If here we wish to capture the `/`, then we might just want to try `([\/]+)`. There should be other expressions to extract `one` also, such as:

```
(?:\/[a-z]+\/)(.+?)(?:\/.+)
```

and our code might look like:

```
regexp_extract(filepath, '(?:\/[a-z]+\/)(.+?)(?:\/.+)', 2)
```

or

```
regexp_extract(filepath, '(?:\/.+?\/)(.+?)(?:\/.+)', 2)
```

---

#### Compartments

In this case, we are not capturing what is behind `one` using a non-capturing group:

```
(?:\/[a-z]+\/)
```

then we capture `one` using:

```
(.+?)
```

and finally we add a right boundary after `one` in another non-capturing group:

```
(?:\/.+)
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Sj7GGe/1)

Depending on which slash, `one` might be located, we can modify our expression. For example, in this case, this expression also might be working:

```
(?:\/.+?\/)(.+?)(?:\/.+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/t4cfZq/1)

Answer (score 1):

The latest Impala versions [use RE2 regex library](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html), and you may easily access capturing group values using the third argument in the [`regex_extract` function](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_extract).

Use the following regex:

```
^/[^/]+/([^/]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mOQtKX/1)  (note that Go regex flavor is also RE2, that is why this option is selected at regex101). It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `/` - a `/` char (no regex delimiters in Impala regex string, hence no need to escape `/` chars in the pattern)
- `[^/]+` - any 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Capturing group 1 (to get it, the *`index`* argument must be set to `1`): any 1 or more chars other than `/`

Code:

```
regexp_extract(filepath, '^/[^/]+/([^/]+)', 1)
```